# how to do this: i press 'G' on textbox and i'll see 'A'?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

how to do this:

when i'll press `'G'` on textbox in my form i'll see `'A'`  ?

in C# code (windows-CE or Windows-mobile)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should handle the KeyPress event. Check if the key pressed is G, if yes, reject the input and put A in the textbox. Try this (The character will be appended to existing text:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 'G')
        {
            // Stop the character from being entered into the control
            e.Handled = true;
            textBox1.Text += 'A';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `textBox1.Text += 'A';` i would prefer `textBox1.AppendText("A");`

Comment: Performance. Just put 10,000 chars into your textBox and let a timer add a random char every 100ms. In the first test use the `+=` approach. In the second the `AppendText()` solution. The problem is that a string is immutable and so the whole string will be taken out of the textbox a single char appended and this whole string will be given back to the TextBox. This tells the Box to throw away its whole content and take the new one, thous leading to nasty flickering.

Comment: Wouldn't there be better my approach?

Answer (score 15):

```
    TextBox t = new TextBox();
    t.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(t_KeyPress);


    void t_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 'G')
            e.KeyChar = 'A';
    }
```